# Android align button and text in a table layout

Tags: uitableview, android-layout, android

I am trying to create a table view with a text view and a button in android. Below is my sample code ( work in progress ). As I am very new to android please help me how to arrange the text view and the button as in the image. Now I am getting button and text view. But its weird.

**My Code**

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_1);          
for (int i = 0; i<30; i++) 
{

 TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
 row.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
 Button btn=new Button(this);

 tv.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.maxWid);
 tv.setText("Sample Text Here");

 row.addView(tv);
 btn.setText("Approves");
 row.addView(btn);
 table.addView(row);

 }
```

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="maxWid">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
</style>
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableLayout  
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout_1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    >  

    </TableLayout>  

</ScrollView>
```

**Expected format**
[image]

Fighting with this since 1 day.. Please help 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

what you can do here is create a layout xml using `RelativeLayout` and then add that into your `TableRow`.

Comment: thanks for your comment.. Sorry for saying that I didnt understand your reply.. my Bad !! Can you give me a sample code please ?

Comment: Create a layout xml file with RelativeLayout as the root node.. then place TextView in it with width as fill_parent and height as wrap_content. then add a Button and give gravity to it as CENTER_VERTICAL|RIGHT and give right margin as you wish to. Button's height and width must be wrap_content and in your code make the following changes:-
`LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();` `row.addView(li.inflate(r.layout.layout_that_we_just_created);`